# What happens at the destination end if it is in a WAN?

Tags: ipv4, subnet, mac-address

When the Sender gets to know that the destination is in a other network ( by doing the AND operation with the subnetting adress of its network ) what are the procedures followed, so the packet does reach at the host side

Suppose we are sending from PC-A to PC-B
My questions are

1. The first packet from the host will contain the destination host's address or default gateway's address as destination ?

   if default gateway's address is there in the header packet as destination, then after reaching to the default gateway's address, how does it know where to ( PC-B ), the data will be sent ? ( because we didn't write the destination address as PC-B rather we wrote destination as default gateway). Does both original Destination address ( PC-B ) and default gateway's address travel at a time ?
2. Assume that data reached at the last router/network. I am sure this time destination address will be of PC-B. So the question is how does the network decides to drop the packet in PC-B ? By comparing its **MAC address or the HOST portion of IP address** of PC-B's address ? ( Please I am really going crazy over this logic, I am not getting any satisfactory answer, please kindly describe it )

Thank You

Admin please, if you think the question is been repeated then please post a link in replay but i have not found the valid/satisfactory answer to my second que.

Comment: be a professional, don't just vote -ve atleast post something so that the inquirer will get know whats the problem.

Comment: Some might say there are [good reasons to downvote without commenting](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328/please-comment-your-downvotes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing layer 2 (MAC) addressing and layer 3 (IP) addressing.  It's a common mistake for beginning networking students.  It doesn’t matter whether you are the first hop or the last hop – the process is the same:

PCs and routers use their hardware address to send data to each other, based on their physical connections.  In the case of Ethernet, it’s the MAC address.   So when one Ethernet device wants to send to another, it uses the MAC address.

PC-A sends a packet with the destination IP address of PC-B.  The MAC address will be the MAC address of the default gateway.

An important thing to remember is that as the packet travels from source to destination, the layer three information (IP address) is unchanged. The MAC addresses change as the data moves from one layer 2 segment to another.  So as the packet moves from router to router, the destination MAC address will be the MAC of the next-hop router.

The Layer 3 (IP) address is used to determine which physical interface the sender will use, and the MAC address of the device on that interface.   Again, whether the recipient is a router or the end host, the process is the same.

The sender uses the network portion of the IP address and the routing table to determine which physical interface to use.   If the routing table indicates a next-hop address, the sender uses ARP to determine the MAC address of the next hop.

If there is no next hop, the sender uses ARP to determine the  MAC address of the end host.
The last hop router will determine that PC-B is on a locally connected network, so will send the data with PC-B's MAC address.  Again, the IP addresses are unchanged.

Comment: Ty Ron, I had never read that from anywhere that IP address doesn't change, now it makes sense. Please one last doubt after reaching the last Router/network it will know that destination host is there, so when it will send the data to the last host, which one it takes as parameter to determine the HOST, MAC address or HOST's IP address. Please clear me if my question is incorrect. Again ty ty.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but when the last hop router sends the packet to the host, it is exactly the same as if PC-A and PC-B are on the same network.  The router determines the host is on the local network, based on the IP address.  It then creates a layer 2 frame and sets the destination MAC address to PC-B.

Comment: ty Ron, ty clearing the basics, I was really struggling there

Comment: Just to be clear one thing, After the packet reaching to the destination network, in the final network it treats as a LAN for forwarding the data, i.e by the help of MAC address. So my question here is whether we use LAN or WAN in the final delivery of data we take the help of MAC address. So what is the need of host portion ( IP address have Network portion, subnett portion and Host portion ) because we don't take the help of host portion for transmitting the data in the final stage, rather we take the help of MAC address. Thank You RON

Comment: I expanded my answer to address your question.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Ty ron for your constant effort to make me explain. Sorry if I am annoying, but the last question, I know you explained all in bit but may be you have left this part, so I am writing this in crystal clear.

Comment: Ty ron for your constant effort to make me explain. Sorry but the last question, After data reaching at the last hop, router gets to know that the destination is in the same network, so it will send a ARP request if it doesn't have the MAC address of the Destination( that you have already explained ). As you first point explains PCs and routers communicate using MAC address. My question **what is the role of HOST portion of an IP address in all these data trasfer** because network portion of IP address is used to get the network where HOST exists & MAC address is used to transfer data to DTE.

Comment: Is the Host portions of an IP address is used only to detect the capabilities of a Network i.e how many numbers of host it can contain ? Or is there any role of Host portions ( except borrowing bits for subnetting ). Because what my point of view is every one is saying host portion is to give a separate name to a HOST in a network, But we do naming to drop the packets ( if we consider the example of post office), but in the end dropping of packet is done by MAC address ( as you have also explained in the first point ).

Comment: Consider if a router had two interfaces connected to two LANs, one LAN is using address range 192.168.1.0/24 with hosts from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.254 and a second LAN with address range 192.168.1.0/24 with hosts using addresses from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254. Let's say that both router interfaces use UP address .254 in their relevant subnet. When this router receives a packet destined to host 192.168.1.37 it can look at its two interface Ip addresses and subnet masks and see that 192.168.1. Is the network portion of one of the interface, .37 falls within the host range of that interface

Comment: ...so 192.168.1.37 is a host attached to the interface with IP address 192.168.1.254. It will send the packet out of that interface with the destination MAC address of the end host as has been described to you above. I hope that little example clears things up a bit.

Comment: The host IP address is used to identify the host at layer 3 -- so the IP process knows that the packet is addressed to that PC.  Think of Layer 2 and the mail carrier who delivers the mail addressed to your house.  But he never looks inside the envelope.  Layer three looks inside the envelope and sees that the letter is addressed to you.

Answer (score 4):

1. The frame from the sender will contain the gateway's MAC address. Within that frame the IP packet will contain PC-B's IP address. The first-hop router will forward the packet based on PC-B's IP address using its IP routing table.
2. If the last-hop router has a directly connected interface in the same network as PC-B but does not have a MAC address for PC-B, it will send an ARP request out onto the network to get PC-B's MAC address. Once it has that, it will forward the packet onto the segment with PC-B's MAC address and PC-B's IP address as the destination.

*Edit:* If PC-A and PC-B are on the same segment, the router doesn't get involved at all. PC-A sends the ARP request for PC-B, and PC-B responds with its MAC address. PC-A then sends the frame onto the segment using PC-B's MAC address as the destination.

Comment: Ty ben. Just for my doubt clarification in case of you point of view ( answer no 2 ), if " last hop-router doesn't have the MAC address of PC-B ", my question is does ARP request always send if the destination is in the same network but the source is not having its MAC ? Also does any router is capable of sending a ARP request ? If yes then who in the router is responsible for initiating the ARP request. I know ARP is off topic to this question but it would be very generous of you if you can answer this please. Thank You

Comment: @dillip_beta I have edited my original answer. Please let me know if that answers your questions.